# Using MKLocalSearch in Swift attaches a pin to the users location instead of the blue dot

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, mklocalsearch

I am new to coding and Stack Overflow, so forgive me if I do something wrong.

I am using MKLocalSearch to display locations specified by a string. I have a user and location, so everything is setup.

I have added MKLocalSearch to my app, and it works correctly but now puts an MKPointAnnotation over the users' location. Of course, I want the famous blue dot to appear rather than an annotation.

I have already tried going over the code and to look up this issue but haven't had any luck finding a solution.

Here is my MKLocalSearch Code:

```swift
let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Dispensaries"
request.region = MapView.region

let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
search.start(completionHandler: {(response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Error occured in search")
    } else if response!.mapItems.count == 0 {
        print("No matches found")
    } else {
        print("Matches found")

        for item in response!.mapItems {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = item.name
            annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.MapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
            print("Name = \(String(describing: item.name))")
            print("Phone = \(String(describing: item.phoneNumber))")
            print("Website = \(String(describing: item.url))")
        }
    }
})
```

Here is my viewForAnnotation

```swift
extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier") as? MKMarkerAnnotationView
        if view == nil {
            view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: nil, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")`

            let identifier = "hold"

            var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

            if annotationView == nil {
                annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
                annotationView?.canShowCallout = true

                let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
                annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
            } else {
                annotationView?.annotation = annotation
            }
        }

        view?.annotation = annotation
        view?.displayPriority = .required

        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show your `viewForAnnotation`; this method needs to return `nil` when the annotation it receives is the user location in order for the map view to provide the default annotation view (blue dot)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I edited my question to hopefully include what you are looking for. Although, I'm not sure it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation)` check the annotation type e.g.

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }

    // the rest of your code
}
```

If you return `nil` from this method, the `MKMapView` uses its default built in annotation views, for `MKPointAnnotation` it uses the red pin, for `MKUserLocation` the blue dot you are looking for.

Comment: Yup! that solved it! Thank you so much, I appreciate it!